# Reinstalling Ubuntu as a solution to my issue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

As I've posted before, Installing Windows 8.1 over Ubuntu has caused the deletion(?) of grub, and thus I cannot get into Ubuntu. I have tried both repairing grub through the command line on a Live USB, and I've also tried Boot Repair. Here's the result of when I tried through the command line:

[image]

As a last effort to help the situation, I'm going to try re-installing Ubuntu over my current install.

Can this be a viable solution to my problem? More importantly, will I lose all my files currently kept on the current install if I do?

Comment: Instead of reinstalling you should investigate what went wrong with the grub-repair. Did you try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: @sinclair that was one of the very first solutions that I attempted. I tried many of the solutions provided there to no avail. In fact, the link / picture posted documents what happens when I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your new  Ubuntu without overwrite the existing one, if you have your home folder on a separate partition, or simply, do not select "Format partition" on the manual install option. The new installation will overwrite the system files and folders, but you will not lose your data, at least, not all. Settings and other things not in your home folder could be overwriten. I suggest you to use your live USB to boot and make a backup of your files, then, do a normal Ubuntu installation to avoid future problems with missing dependencies, settings, etc.

Comment: I think you can even repair a broken Linux installation. When you select install the installer looks for installed OSes. It will most probably find the installed Linux ans propose to repair it. In that way it should reinstall system files, leave your files intact and make linux bootable.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I shall preform the new installation soon, and hopefully that solves my issue.